# Need To Change my bluetooth Printer Mode to ZPL Mode - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

my printer is of type TSC ALPHA-4L , I can connect to it and send orders to it but print nothing,
I tried to install app to try print on it the printer only print when I change the printer mode to ZPL mode , so how can I change the Printer mode to ZPL inside my Flutter app?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZTwW.jpg)
printer : https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/tsc-alpha-4l-label-printer-22570101491.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you resolve this issue?